# CKEDITOR 4: How to reuse the already available icon in context submenu.?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, contextmenu

I have an context menu with some sub-menu items. I tried to set as follow

```
    editor.addMenuGroup('newMenu'); 
    editor.addCommand("submenu1", { exec: function(b) { alert('submenu1'); } });
    editor.addCommand("submenu2", { exec: function(b) { alert('submenu2'); } });
    editor.addMenuItems && editor.addMenuItems({
        newMenuItem: {
            label: "Menu1", group: "newMenu", order: 1,
            getItems: function() {
                return {
                    submenu1: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
                    submenu2: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF
                }
            }
        },

        submenu1: {
           label: "Sub-Menu1",
           group: "newMenu", 
           command: "submenu1",
           icon:CKEDITOR.getUrl('plugins/icons.png'), //Here adding the icon,first icon only coming
           order: 2
           },
        submenu2: { 
           label: "Sub-Menu2", 
           group: "newMenu", 
           command: "submenu2",
           icon:CKEDITOR.getUrl('plugins/icons.png'),//Here adding the icon,first icon only coming
           order: 3
         }
       });
```

Here for the both the sub menu items icons are coming as same. And its taking the first icon of the icons.png. I know i am missing something here to mention the position of an icon, but i dont know how to give that position here. Anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you got to do is to register the icon as a part of the skin ([`CKEDITOR.skin.addIcon`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.skin-method-addIcon)). Once you do it, you can basically refer to it by its name ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/N6TyP/)):

```
// Define the icon as a part of the skin first.
CKEDITOR.skin.addIcon( 'twitter', 'https://abs.twimg.com/favicons/favicon.ico' );

var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    plugins: 'wysiwygarea,sourcearea,basicstyles,toolbar',
    on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function() {           
            this.ui.addButton( 'Foo', {
                label: 'Foo',
                command: 'bold',
                // Use it!
                icon: 'twitter'
            });         

            this.ui.addButton( 'Bar', {
                label: 'Bar',
                command: 'italic',
                // Use it once again!
                icon: 'twitter'
            });             
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Great.. I have asked for context menu, anyway `CKEDITOR.skin.addIcon` works for me.

Comment: Can we have any option to remove the added Icon.?

Comment: Try messing with `CKEDITOR.skin.icons` object. Maybe it will do for you.

Comment: LOL. I have tried like this `CKEDITOR.skin.icons[iconname].path=""` and it works. And dont know about cross browsers.